# List attribute update in child Class

Tags: python, oop

Is this possible in Python (2.7) to update a list attribute in derived constructor?

Consider following example:

```
 class Parent(object):  
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        value1      = 'P1'
        self.value2 = 'P2'
        self.parentList= [value1, self.value2]
```

My `parentList` is initialized as: `['P1', 'P2']`.
I would like my `Child` class constructor to update one of the values stored in `parentList`.

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, data):
        Parent.__init__(self, data)
        value3 = 'C3'   
        value4 = 'C4'
        #how update parentList?
        self.childList = [value3, value4, ???]
```

Expected behaviour is to **update** `value2` to get `childList` like below:

`childList= ['C3','C4', 'P1, 'P2_modified']`

If possible this should be solved on a 'class' level becasue there will be multiple inheritance going underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much in the way of access modifiers in Python. Once you have your child object, you should be able to access parent attributes at will. For example:

```
~/Desktop> cat a.py
class P(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = [1, 2]

class C(P):
    def __init__(self):
        P.__init__(self)
        self.l[1] = "2mod"
        self.l.append(3)

print C().l
~/Desktop> python a.py
[1, '2mod', 3]
```

Beyond that, it's probably a matter of your specific class hierarchy. If each element in your list can be identified by some key, you could use a dictionary instead, and each class in the hierarchy could potentially just add its own keys independently of the others, or update existing keys (although it might depend on the order base classes are specified, and it gets more complicated).

Comment: Using dictionaries would be ok, im am on the stage that this could be implemented hovewer i really need ordered collection. I've been thinking of OrderedDict but not quite sure if possible in my  case..

Comment: Maybe something similar to Java's `LinkedHashMap`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow what you are trying to achieve.

See the comments inline for some examples of things you can do with the data structures you showed.

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, data):
        Parent.__init__(self, data)
        value3 = 'C3'   
        value4 = 'C4'

        # You can change 'self.value2' by assigning to it:
        self.value2 = 'P2_modified'

        # You can create this new list with the value:
        self.childList = [value3, value4, self.parentList[0], self.value2]

        # You can also modify the existing list object:
        self.parentList[1] = self.value2
```